# ASP.net Paraccel connection string

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, paraccel

I am wondering if anyone knows how to connect an ASP.net application to paraccel? I am very new to ASP.net development, just installed visual studio. However I am tasked with creating a web service that connects to paraccel in order for another non asp.net application to get what it needs. I understand the connectionstring needs to be set in the Web.config file, however I cannot find any samples of this for paraccel

Answer (score 0):

I believe Amazon's Redshift [product](http://www.zdnet.com/amazon-redshift-paraccel-in-costly-appliances-out-7000008111/) is based on the ParAccel parallel datawarehouse.  You need to use [Npgsql](http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/documentation.html) to connect to a ParAccel datawarehouse.